# How to Paste to specific sheet based on textbox value?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste certain rows into a certain sheet if a string is entered into a textbox.

I have is a userform that I'd like to paste entries into Month specific sheets based on the date textbox.

I can copy to one specific sheet, but I'd like to auto sort into the appropriate Month sheet based on the value entered in `DT.value`.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

If DT.Value = "nov" Then
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NOV")
Else
    If DT.Value = "dec" Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DEC")
    Else
        If DT.Value = "Jan" Then
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JAN")
        Else
            If DT.Value = "Feb" Then
                Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FEB")
            Else
                If DT.Value = "mar" Then
                    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAR")
                Else
                    If DT.Value = "Apr" Then
                        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("APR")
                        LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'other code that works below.
```

With this code I end up with Type Mismatch or nothing gets copied.

I'd like the user to enter a date in the `dt.value` box and the data paste to the appropriate sheet based on that value.

Comment: What is DT.Value?

Comment: It's a textbox DT.Text usually but i was experimenting with value

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in you VBA editor to figure out what line the error occurs on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you have named your tabs and how your date is imputed in the textbox. 
But if you are using `mar` and `MAR`, here is a simple code to assign the worksheet variable using the text in the userform textbox.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.DT.Text)
```

Update to basic code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'Check if the textbox has a valid date
    If IsDate(Me.DT.Text) Then

        Me.DT.Text = Format(CDate(Me.DT.Text), "mmm") 'Format as abrivated month

        'Define and Assign worksheet and newRow variables
        Dim ws As Worksheet, newRow As Long
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.DT.Text)
        newRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        With ws 'When writing other textbox values to the worksheet; change TextBox# as required
            .Cells(newRow, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
            .Cells(newRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
            .Cells(newRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox3.Text
            .Cells(newRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox4.Text
        End With

        Application.Goto ws.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True 'Set the focus to the first cell on the worksheet

    Else 'If a valid date is not entered display a message box
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid date"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It works! Only issue is now it won't paste the date that was entered into the text box, it only pastes the 3 character month. I need it to display the entire date in the cell

Comment: What cell do you want to paste the date from DT?

Comment: ws.Range("A" & newRow).Value = Format(DT.Text, "Long Date")
Column A :)